# lftp: how to echo an unsupported command to remote server

Tags: linux, ftp

I am connecting to a remote server that requires that I change my password every 90 days (WS_FTP Pro).  The command to do that is "CPWD oldpass newpass".

I would like to do it using a script but I can't figure out how to send the CPWD command using lftp.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `quote (your command)`.  So, in your case, `quote CPWD oldpass newpass`

Comment: It doesn't work.------Command: SITE CPWD thispass thatpass----Response: 550 Command SITE failed-----If I use filezila and "Enter custom command..." I get/-----Command: CPWD thispass thatpass---Response: 250 CPWD successful

Comment: How about `quote cpwd oldpass newpass`?

Comment: *in best carnival barker voice* WINNAR! ty

Comment: Nice!  I'll edit my answer to have the correct one.